# easiest ways to convert a mac osx app to an ios app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, macos

I have a mac osx application and am trying to convert it to an ios app but am running into a lot of trouble in doing so.  I was hoping that someone out there might know about a converter that I can use and if no such thing exists what is the easiest way to go about doing this.  I am currently using the latest version of xcode to do this if that makes any difference.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanking You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no silver bullet for this; it has to be done by hand.

You can probably reuse some of the "model" code, since both Mac and iOS use an MVC pattern, but the "view" code has to be written basically from scratch.

Comment: agreed, good, consequent use of MVC helps but the GUI (most often) has to be rewritten completely. Sometimes it is good -if your controller layer is fat- to move stuff to the 'model'